# Modify text file in Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I just asked a bit of misplaced question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058324/write-text-to-a-file-in-azure-storage)  .I am a complete newbie to Azure,so plz bear with me.

I have a text file uploaded in my Azure storage account.Now, in my worker role , what i need to do is every time it is run, it fetches some content from Database, and that content must be written in the Uploaded text file, specifically , each time the content of Text file should be overwritten with some new content.

I want to know,is there a way of modifying a text file, without the usual way of downloading it locally , and then modifying and uploading it again.

I am looking of some way ,like the way it is read , in form of a text,using "DownloadToStream".I mean,cant we just upload some text stream in the text file present.

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more about the structure of the file? Is the file structure predefined or it could be random? When you wish to modify the file, do you wish to modify the file at random places or do you know exactly where modifications need to be done?

Comment: i know eaxtly whre it will be done...also the structure is fixed,it text file,containing a single column..

Answer (score 1):

Given that your file structure is fixed, let's take an example. Assuming your file looks something like this where each entry is in a new line:

```
Line1: this is line 1
Line2: this is line 2
Line3: this is line 3
...
...
...
```

Now when you're uploading a new file (assuming the file is not present), irrespective of the size of the file, you would need to upload them in blocks using Put Block and Commit Block List. What you will do is assign a block id for each line (ideally you would like to give block id the same as the line number e.g 000001, 000002 etc.) and put those lines. Once the entire file is uploaded, you would commit the block list.

Next when want to update the file, first thing you would do is get the committed block list. Now let's assume you want to change line #2. What you will do is put block operation on the 2nd block and provide the new content. Once that block is committed, you would need to commit the block list again.

Here's the sample code which illustrates the stuff I mentioned above:

```
    var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("myaccount", "accountkey"), true);
    var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = client.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
    container.CreateIfNotExists();
    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("so.txt");
    List<string> blockIds = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int j = i + 1;
        var blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(j.ToString("d6")));
        blockIds.Add(blockId);
        string content = "Line " + j + ": this is line #" + j + "\r\n";
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
        {
            blob.PutBlock(blockId, ms, null);
        }
    }
    blob.PutBlockList(blockIds);
    int j1 = 2;
    var blockIdNew = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(j1.ToString("d6")));
    string newContent = "Line " + j1 + ": this is line #" + j1 + " - this is modified.\r\n";
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newContent)))
    {
        blob.PutBlock(blockIdNew, ms, null);
    }
    blob.PutBlockList(blockIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("*****"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer objContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("****");
CloudBlockBlob blob = objContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("file.txt");

string content = blob.DownloadTextAsync().Result + report;
blob.UploadTextAsync(content);
blob.SetProperties();
```

Comment: Please add more context to what your code is doing.